# how to install mysql to existing docker file

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to add mysql to a dockerfile.  I dont want to use a mysql source docker, I'm using something else as I need ffmpeg/nvidia/asp.net aswell.  So I can't simple use a different base image to start from.

So how can I

1. Add mysql to my docker build file?
2. Configure it so the data for mysql is in a specific directory (so I can can map outside the docker file)
3. Have mysql start up but not be the entry point service

Everything I found so far basically say "use this base image".  which doesn't help me.  I dont want to have mysql separate, just self contained docker image with everything it needs.

TIA

Comment: You will generally want to run only one process per container; containers don't have "services" _per se_ and running something as "not the entry point service" is significantly more complicated.  That means you should almost always run MySQL as a separate container, at which point using the unmodified Docker Hub `mysql` image is fine.

Comment: thanks, I really dont want to do that.  From a users presepective thats just more complicated for them to get it up and running.   So looking for a way to have it run both.  I could I suppose have my app just start mysql as a separate process when it starts....

Answer (score 1):

## Install mysql

Use `apt-get` to install packages on `debian` distro's. Add in your dockerfile the following line:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

## Start MySQL

Add to the Dockerfile CMD a prefix where you start mysql in detached mode. Like:

```
CMD mysql start & # [paste here your default command]`.
```

This will start `mysql` and start your app.

## Mount directories

Mounting directories is done with the `-v` flag:

```
docker run -ti -v <host_dir>:<container_dir>  my-image /bin/bash
```

Comment: that will install it, but it wont start it or set the data directory for me.

Comment: Yes, if you want to mount volumes, use the `-v` flag like: `docker run -ti -v <host_dir>:<container_dir>  my-image /bin/bash`. Add to the `Dockerfile` `CMD` a prefix where you start mysql in detached mode. Like: `CMD mysql start & # here the rest of your default command`. I edited the answer.